# Conditional update many in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Finding and updating specified field in mongo is quite easy;

`User.updateMany({ name: 'Mary' }, { $set: { age: 18 } }, { multi: true })`

However it will only find elements that have `name` set to `Mary`.

In my case, I want to update **every element** which field `name` is longer than 3 characters and field `checked` is true.

`if (name.length > 3 && checked === true) then $set: { age: 18 }`

### Question: How to do such conditional update in mongo? Thanx!

Comment: Which version of Mongo are you using? In 3.4+ you can use $strLenCP as part of an aggregation pipeline to query the string length. Then you can use this with the $gt operator

Comment: @RobertSeaman Im using mongoose 5+, dunno about mongodb version exactly

Comment: `.updateMany({ "checked": true, "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$name" }, 3 ] } }, { .. same $set statement` or `{ "checked": true, "$where": "this.name.length > 3" }` for older versions without `$expr`. Note also `{ multi: true }` is "implied" by `updateMany()` and not required.

Comment: Either update() or updateMany() can do the job. It depends on what you have in mind. the difference is that update() by default modifies only a single document but if you include the modifier {multi: true}, then it can operate as updateMany which finds and modifies all documents matching the filter.